# what is the `for` construct in a Swift function definition

Tags: swift

I've seen the string `for` In a function definition in front a parameter a few times now. That's not something I've read about. What is that?

e.g:

```
func aFunc(param1: Int, param2: String, `for` param3: Double) {
}
```

Comment: Note that in Swift 3 you don't have to escape  `for` as an external parameter name anymore: `func aFunc(param1: Int, param2: String, for param3: Double)`, compare https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0071-member-keywords.md.

Comment: Oh, for was considered a keyword in Swift 2, so using for as a local parameter name had to be escaped? The escaping was the part that confused me. I vaguely remember escaping now.